# How to format shapes in Diagrams.net based on the type

Tags: formatting, customization, flowchart, diagrams.net

I would like to customize shapes format based on their type.
For example - Decision (Diamond) is pink and Step (Rectangle) is red. It seems that the only way is to have the same format for all shapes.

Have you come across this before?

Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use the scratchpad.

Insert a diamond, format the line to be pink, then drag it to the scratchpad. Insert a rectangle, format the line to be red, then drag that to the scratchpad. You can then insert shapes by either clicking in the scratchpad or dragging from the scratchpad.

You may need to make one more change in your workflow. If you use the arrows around a shape to create your flowchart you will find that the inserted shape is the same colour as the previous shape. That is fine for inserting several processes, but wrong if you want to connect a process to a decision, or vice versa. Instead, drag the new shape from the scratchpad to the arrow.

Connectors inherit their colour from the default style, which allows another colour in your diagram if you wish.

In practice I find it easier to draw the flowchart using the default colours, select all of the processes (click, shift-click, shift-click, ...) change the line colour, then repeat for the decisions.